# elementary OS VM on new laptop and AMD video card, how to change video driver

Tags: pantheon, amd, radeon

I have a Virtual Box VM of Elementary OS Freya that was moved to a new laptop. The old laptop (Intel Celeron) had integrated Intel Graphics card. New laptop (AMD A8 5550M) has AMD Radeon HD 8550 G card. When I start the VM I get the familiar Elementary e logo, but then some text and the screen does not continue to the desktop. I can switch to tty using CtlAltF1 which presents me with tty login. Login is successful and I can get around the file system. I discovered how to get to the grub menu to modify the parameters but have not a clue what parameters if any will help.

How do I "fix" my broken video configuration to use the AMD drivers and get back to Pantheon? I have no preference regarding open vs. proprietary drivers, I just want my lovely Elementary back. I am very noob to Linux so any useful help is appreciated (including pointers to Ask Ubuntu if that is where I need to be asking).

Comment: All VMs use the same hardware so there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: More info: I created a new VM to run the Try Elementary Live CD option. Same outcome: the graphic screen is black, but I can switch to the tty terminal in the Live CD VM. I reran with `acpi=off` and `nomodeset` as advised on other sites, but with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Virtual Box forum provided an answer so I thought I would share it in case anyone else encounters this problem. The solution was to Enable 3D Acceleration on the VM.